# Create a stored procedure to delete rows that have no values

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, inner-join, procedure

Create a stored procedure called sp_del_inactive_cust to delete customers that have no orders.  The stored procedure should delete 1 row.

Here is the database I am working with.
[image: database diagram]
<sub>(source: [bcitwebdev.com](http://students.bcitwebdev.com/jlandon/school/1630/databasediagram.png))</sub>

My immediate thought is that I need to check the customers table against the orders table. If the customer is present in the customers table but not in the orders table, that must mean that they have not created any order ids under their customer id. Then, I must delete the customer if they do not have any orders.

I'm not really sure how to go about scripting this problem. I need help! Please keep it simple as I am a first semester student.

Here's something I've tried starting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE     sp_del_inactive_cust
AS
SELECT               customers.customer_id,
                 orders.customer_id
FROM         customers
INNER JOIN           orders ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id
WHERE        /* customer_id is found in customers table but not in orders table */
```

And then I will execute the procedure.

This question has been answered thanks to the help of Michael Fredrickson.

Here are the final statements which deleted the required 1 row:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE        sp_del_inactive_cust
AS
DELETE                  customers
FROM                    customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN         orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE                   orders.customer_id IS NULL;
GO

EXECUTE                 sp_del_inactive_cust;
GO
```

Comment: You can't create a trigger for this as every record you would enter in the customer table will have no orders at a the time of entry. You would do this in a job that runs hourly or so.

Comment: Okay so if not a trigger, how else would I run this procedure? I have not learned about how to run a job.

Comment: Oh and never ever name a stored proc sp_ - system procs use that.

Comment: And the stored procedure should most definitely NOT delete one row. That would cause the table to never be up-to-date if multiple rows are added at once.  If you teacher is asking you to do such a stupid thing, he or she is clearly incomptent. You  want to things in sets in databases and never think just one row at a time.

Comment: Okay well... I'm going to name it that as that is what is required by my school.

Comment: I think what I've missed here is that the procedure must be executed for it to delete one row. It won't just trigger by itself. Perhaps the question was worded improperly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_del_inactive_cust

AS

DELETE TOP (1) c
FROM
    customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o
        ON C.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE
    o.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: SOrry I orginally missed the one record requirement, I have removed the downvote and replaced it with an upvote

Comment: @HLGEM Thank you sir... I would agree that I don't think this is the right solution to the problem... but it sounds like the OP has just got a crazy professor giving weird requirements.

Comment: Sadly, what he is teaching is actively dangerous. I certainly would not allow anyone near my database that programmed the way this person is teaching.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. Tweaked it a bit. I will edit my original post.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create an anti-join to get the customers that have placed no orders, like this:

```
DELETE c FROM
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.customer_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to just give you the answer so I will give you an example of the inverse and let you figure out the rest

here is an example

2 tables 
foo {foo_id, a, b, c} 
bar {bar_id, foo_Id, e, f, g}

If i want to delete all records from foo that appear in the bar table I would write

delete foo 
where foo_id in (select foo_id from bar)

look up the "in" keyword for a real explanation
also there are always many ways of doing something and you might not get the proper grade in a class if you dont do things the way the teacher wants

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE customers 
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Orders)
```